# How to zip align in new eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I read a tutorial on how to zip align in the old version of eclipse (right click `project > android tools > export signed application package`) but in the new version, there is no android tools option and I've tried searching for an export signed application package option but I can't find one.

Need to do this as Google Play are telling me my APK is not zip aligned.

Comment: You should add some more information to your question: what Eclipse are you using, what plugins you have added (in which version), ... So others may know what your context is, and the ones with experience here may answer. Do you have searched for documentation, help files, ... that did not help? This could be information that helps others to understand what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can sign the application in the eclipse easily using wizard. You won't have run the zip align command on the command prompt.

Go to

```
File->Export->Android->Export Android Application.
```

[image: Eclipse App Sign Wizard]

It does all the things which is required to sign the app.

> Command for the zip align

To align infile.apk and save it as outfile.apk:

```
zipalign [-f] [-v] <alignment> infile.apk outfile.apk
```

Comment: There is no "Android" option on export.

Comment: There is Android option in the above screenshot, See above

Comment: I have the latest version of Eclipse and there is no Android option showing

Comment: It might you did not add the Android plugin/ADT in the eclipse then you can do using the command which I covered in the answer